# Finding a proper tricky Dice constructor

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to make a class which represents a Dice, sometimes the Dice gets tricked, i.e. The probability to get one side is most than others, so to get the constructor I get this:

```
//sides and color are defined as integers
//sum as a double
public Dice(double[] probability) {
    probability = new double[6];
    sides = 6;
    color = 0; //not relevant
    lastFace = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        sum += probability[i];
    }
    if(sum >= 0.9 && sum <= 1)
        setTricky(probability); //method defined to set a boolean
    else{
        System.out.println("Sorry, but your probability is not valid.");
        trciky = false;
    }
}
```

So, at the main method I've got something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double[] prob = new double[6];
System.out.println("Type the values of probability for each side of your Dice (it must to be 6).");
for (int i = 0; i < prob.length; i++){
      prob[i] = sc.nextDouble();
}
Dice d2 = new Dice(prob);
```

When I type the doubles for the values of the array (for example {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1 0.1}) it shows me that `sum` is not on the rank. So, what can I do?

Comment: with `probability = new double[6];` in your constructor you overwrite the reference to the passed in array with a reference to a new, empty array (meaning: all values in the new double array are 0.0). Remove this line and your problem is solved

Comment: you are not using the passed argument due to this one: `probability = new double[6];` remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has already been pointed out, the line

```
probability = new double[6];
```

in your constructor is over-writing the parameter that is passed in. This is because you're assigning the variable name "probability" from the array that contains your probabilities to a new array of doubles.

Simply taking that line out should fix the problem.